# How does `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})` work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

On https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input they give an example of using onChangeText with:

```
  <View style={{padding: 10}}>
    <TextInput
      style={{height: 40}}
      placeholder="Type here to translate!"
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    />
```

I don't exactly understand why `this.state.text` is set to the value of `TextInput`. How exactly does it work? I understand anonymous function is used here, but still can't see where `this.state.text` is initiated. Can you show an example of a similar thing with plain javascript?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not just an anonymous function.  That's an anonymous arrow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but still can't see where this.state.text is initiated

it's actually initialized in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {text: ''}; // initialized here
}
```

> I don't exactly understand why this.state.text is set to the value of TextInput

whenever the user type text in the `input`, the `onChangeText` function is called which actually update the state => the `text` variable will take the value of the text input

Moreover, when you call `setState` it will re-render the component, so

```
<Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
  {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
</Text>
```

will be re-executed and you will see a  symbol for each word typed by the user

Comment: What I don't understand how is the key (`text` in this case) found by doing this: `(text) => this.setState({text})`

Comment: `TextInput` comes from react native library, you can see the doc here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext react native calls this function (with one argument, the text typed by the user) when the text input is changed

Comment: How does react now to update state of `text` field? If I did `{(text2) => this.setState({text2})}` it would try to update field `text2`, right? How and why then?

Comment: How does react now to update state of `text` field? If I did `{(text2) => this.setState({text2})}` it would try to update field `text2`, right? How and why then?

Comment: `this.setState({text})` is a shortcut for `this.setState({text: text})` it's part of es6 feature https://gist.github.com/vasco3/22b09ef0ca5e0f8c5996#object-short-hand you can write `(text2) => this.setState({text: text2})` it will give the same result

Comment: Ok, that's what I missed, I didn't know about the shortcut. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The onChangeText is listening for changes to the input. That is your text in regards to (text). We then use es6 arrow notation to call an anonymous function => . From here we call this.setState({}) , which is a built in state management function with react. It sets the variable, (which may or may not be declared) in state to the changed value of (text) to be used later or elsewhere.

The confusion might be that if you didn't declare text yourself, as such,

```
this.state = { text: ''}
```

It would be confusing how its actually storing if you didn't have text already in your state, but saw it updating. But in react, it will create a new state variable even if you didn't declare one automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to recreate this functionality with plain js? I still can't understand how exactly it works. Where it gets the key that it sets value to.

Answer (score 0):

Only place you directly write to `this.state` should be the Components constructor. In other places you should be using `this.setState` function, which accepts an Object that is merged into Components current state.

It's possible to alter state by writing to `this.state` directly, However it will not lead to Component re-rendering with new data, and generally lead to state inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand anonymous function is used here, but still can't see where this.state.text is initiated.

That's just example of code. You must specify initial state to make onChangeText work inside the constructor. FYI, that's not just an anonymous function, but an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
this.state = {
  text: ''
}
```

> Can you show an example of a similar thing with plain javascript?

I think you meant to use in other way? If so, you can use like this:

Define a method:

```
onChangeText(text) {
  this.setState({text})
  // ^^ alias of -> this.setState({text:text})
}
```

Use `onChangeText` method:

```
onChangeText={this.onChangeText(text)}
```

Bind `this` inside the constructor:

```
this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

this.state.text is part of the [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) of the component.

> I don't exactly understand why this.state.text is set to the value of TextInput

It is stored in the state so that other components can access the value and use it. (For example: Form submission needs all values.)

For a TextInput form submission example :

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  mySubmitService(this.state.textInput)
}
```

Another example from the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) :

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {date: new Date()}; //This is the default state initialization
}

render() {
  return (
   <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2> //This is accessing the value 
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Plain JS :

```
var data = +(document.getElementById("TextInputId").value;);
```